# How to migrate Jenkins job from windows local machine to Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I installed Jenkins in my local machine(Windows) & I have created one new job using Jenkins and it's works perfectly... Now I have installed Jenkins in one dedicated Linux Server... How to migrate the job from windows(local machine) to newly installed Jenkins on Linux server??

Answer (score 1):

The safest solution is to use the [Job Import plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin).

Install this plugin on the Linux server, and next import the job from the Windows Jenkins URL :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.. I have tried Job Import Plugin.. I entered Remote Jenkins URL & clicks Query.. Nothing displayed

Comment: Remote Jenkins installed in my localhost. Still the plugin works for me

Comment: So you need to use your localhost URL as the remote Jenkins. This plugin helped to solve your issue?

Comment: I have tried with my localhost URL as the remote jenkins, nothing get displayed...

Comment: If you copy the jobs folder from your Windows machine to the Linux server + a restart of the jenkins app, you should see your jobs.

Comment: Job folder you are telling that the directory present inside the jenkins directory..?

Comment: Yep, in the Jenkins home folder (on your Windows machine), you'll find a jobs folder. If the Linux server is a fresh install (no Jenkins jobs), please copy this jobs folder from the Windows machine.

Comment: Only Job folder is enough? What about workspace & source files..?

Comment: Because config.xml in Job folder(windows machine) contains custom workspace as <my local directory> & command as <windows batch file>

Comment: If you want to copy only the job definition, the jobs folder is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check in your Job's configs with some smart .gitignore (or whatever your choice of SCM is) and use the %JENKINS_HOME% as a checked in and versioned directory in the SCM of your choice.

Job config's are OS independent, though the job itself might have OS specific scripts (if you use a shell script instead of a mvn pom file / ant build.xml).

Then you can just check out your checked in job repo to the new linux host's $jenkins_home directory and start up jenkins.  all your jobs should be found and added to your linux jenkins (with out the need for a plugin).

Generally speaking... the less plugins, the more stable your Jenkins install will be.

Comment: HI JasonRobinson, I have no idea what you said.. I just uploaded src, bin,lib directories & testng.xml file and batch file from local machine to Linux Server & created new workspace there. I am trying to build new job with help of the uploaded files. But while building Jenkins console throws a Failure. Even though same script files runs perfectly in my local machine.. Where the actual problem is in above condition.?

Comment: Jenkins keeps all its data in xml format in the %JENKINS_HOME% directory.  The structure looks like this:

Comment: Jenkins keeps all its data in xml format in the %JENKINS_HOME% directory.  The structure looks like this:Directories:

 * jobs
 * nodes
 * plugins
 * secrets
 * updates
 * userContent

The jobs directory can be checked in to any source control and that will preserve the state of your jobs.  You can check out the repository into a new jenkins and reboot jenkins to catch all the imported jobs that you previously checked in to source control.